# How to translate text using gettext in vue?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, gettext

I have many component which contain static texts, I would like to translate these text from polish language to english language and vice versa using gettext plugin.

Here is how texts look in my components .

```
<h1>   {{ __('Mail kontaktowy') }}</h1>

<p>   {{ __('Dziękujemy za kontakt') }}</p>

<h3>   {{ __('Twoja wiadomość') }}</h3>
```

Solution I have tried according to documentations online

installed plugin:

```
 npm install vue-gettext
```

Here is configuration per my needs

```
// ES6
import Vue from 'vue'
import GetTextPlugin from 'vue-gettext'
import translations from './path/to/translations.json'

Vue.use(GetTextPlugin, {
  availableLanguages: {
    en_GB: 'British English',
    en_US: 'American English',
    pl_PL: 'Polish',
  },
  defaultLanguage: 'pl_PL',
  languageVmMixin: {
    computed: {
      currentKebabCase: function () {
        return this.current.toLowerCase().replace('_', '-')
      },
    },
  },
  translations: translations,
  silent: True,
})
```

HTML calling gettext to translate those texts

```
   <h1 v-translate>{{ __('Mail kontaktowy') }}</h1>
```

This does not work, what am i doing wrong in my implementations? Please help am new to vue , am strugling how get those text translated (assume i have a lot of static text).

Comment: what is the purpose of the `__` function? I don't see any reference in your code or the docs for `vue-gettext`

Answer (score 2):

I searched about vue-gettext and from the documentation here: https://vuejsexamples.com/translate-your-vue-js-applications-with-gettext/, you can translate a text by using the translate component:

```
<translate>Hello!</translate>
```

or using the v-translate directive:

```
<span v-translate>Hello!</span>
```

I don't see the use of having the `__` in your code, unless you have a function for that. I think this would work already:

```
<h1 v-translate>Mail kontaktowy</h1>
```

Comment: hi Jaye, Its template I found somewhere and there is not any where in app implemnented this underscore, its just written I need to use gettex to translate

Comment: What happens when the underscore and parenthesis are removed?