# How to transalte static text using vue-gettext in laravel with blade engine?

Tags: html, laravel, vue.js, gettext

I have many template which contain static texts, I would like to translate these text from polish language to english language and vice versa using gettext plugin. am using blade engine

Here is how texts look in my templates .

```
<h1>   {{ __('Mail kontaktowy') }}</h1>

<p>   {{ __('Dziękujemy za kontakt') }}</p>

<h3>   {{ __('Twoja wiadomość') }}</h3>
```

Solution I have tried according to documentations online

installed plugin:

```
 npm install vue-gettext
```

Here is configuration per my needs

```
// ES6
import Vue from 'vue'
import GetTextPlugin from 'vue-gettext'
import translations from './path/to/translations.json'

Vue.use(GetTextPlugin, {
  availableLanguages: {
    en_GB: 'British English',
    en_US: 'American English',
    pl_PL: 'Polish',
  },
  defaultLanguage: 'pl_PL',
  languageVmMixin: {
    computed: {
      currentKebabCase: function () {
        return this.current.toLowerCase().replace('_', '-')
      },
    },
  },
  translations: translations,
  silent: True,
})
```

HTML calling gettext to translate those texts

```
   <h1 v-translate>{{ __('Mail kontaktowy') }}</h1>
```

This does not work, what am i doing wrong in my implementations? Please help am new to vue , am strugling how get those text translated (assume i have a lot of static text).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to translate text using gettext in vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749396/how-to-translate-text-using-gettext-in-vue)

Comment: @tony its not just check well

Comment: This question is almost identical to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749396/how-to-translate-text-using-gettext-in-vue) you had asked earlier today (i.e., a duplicate). Please don't duplicate questions simply because you're unsatisfied with received answers.

Comment: I asked wrong way that is why I created new thread instead of deleting answered qn

Comment: The difference between your two questions are trivial with only a few words that changed. They're essentially the same question, so the answer would have still applied.